# javascript string regex (css validity check+conversion)

Tags: javascript, css, regex, validation

given a string such as one of the following:

```
'2'
'2px'
'2%'
'2em'
'2foobar'
'foobar'
```

I would like to determine:

1) whether it is a plain number (2 or 2.2), and if it is round it (Math.floor()) and append 'px' to it, so that, '2' or '2.2' becomes '2px'

2) if it's not a plain number determine if it is a valid css value, that is, if it consist of a number (int or float) followed by either 'px', 'em' or '%'. I know there are others but I'll just support those three. If it is, leave it.

3) if not, see if the string begins with a number (int ot float), round it and append 'px'

4) and if not, set it to an empty string

So that the result would be:

```
'2'     -> '2px'
'2.2'   -> '2px'

'2%'    -> '2%'
'2em'   -> '2em'

'2foo' -> '2px'

'foo'  -> ''
```

Is it possible to do this in a compact way (maybe using regex), or by using an existing css validator library for JS?

Comment: I've found this http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation .. will have a look at it to see how it could be extended to validate for the patterns I need here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how with a regex:

```
var input = '2.7em', output = parseInt(input, 10) + (input.match(/px|%|em/) || 'px')
```

edit:

```
var input = '2.7foo'
, number = parseInt(input, 10)
, output = (isNaN(number)) ? '': number + (input.match(/px|%|em/) || 'px');
```

edit 2: allow for float with em and %:

```
var inp='3.5em'
, n=parseFloat(inp), p=inp.match(/%|em/)
, output = (isNaN(n)) ? '': (p)?n+p:Math.round(n)+'px';
```

Comment: Your example works, and I find it the most elegant for the given problem, but I get an error if the input.match does not find one of the patterns its looking for. If input is set to '10foo' I get an TypeError: No Prperties. See here http://www.ideone.com/cwlgI  can you tweak it to fix this, then this would be a perfect solution.

Comment: this one also has the problem of converting floats to ints too early in the game.. floats should keep their decimals for inputs containing 'em' or '%'

Answer (score 2):

```
var input  = '2foo';
var output = '';
var tmp;

tmp = parseInt( input.replace(/^[^1-9]*/, '') );
if ( tmp != 'NaN' ) {
  if ( tmp + '%' == input ) {
    output = tmp + '%';
  } else if ( tmp + 'em' == input ) {
    output = tmp + 'em';
  } else {
    output = tmp + 'px';
  }
}
```

Comment: super, parseInt really solves it all in one go here.. One thing to watch out for is that according to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp any leadning zeros should be striped from the input before processing, as that would trigger octal mode: parseInt('010') gives 8

Comment: I've edited my answer - it removes now everything from beginning that is not a 1-9 number.

Comment: this wont wok with floats. input =2.2em, tmp = 2, tmp+'em' != input so output = tmp+'px'

Comment: this is fixed in the modified version i posted below

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you asked for an regular expression... Anyway, it's also possible by parsing the value as int or float and *subtract* it from the original value.

```
var input = '2.2px';
var value = parseInt(input, 10) // => 2
var unit = input.split(value)[1] // => 'px'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few CSS parsers written in JS, not sure how robust they are at parsing numbers. Regex may be your best option.

https://github.com/stubbornella/parser-lib

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. Here is a tested solution which uses one regex and a switch statement:

```js
function clean_css_value(text) {
    var re = /^(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([^\d\s]+)?$/m;
    // Case 0: String does not match pattern at all.
    if (!(m = text.match(re))) return '';
    // Case 1: No number at all? return '';
    if (!m[1]) return '';
    var i = Math.floor(m[1]); // Compute integer portion.
    // Case 2: Nothing after number? return integer pixels
    if (!m[2]) return i + 'px';
    switch (m[2]) {
    case 'em':
    case '%':
        return m[1] + m[2];
    case 'px':
    default:
        return i + 'px';
    }
}
```

Note that this function also works for fractional numbers having no integer portion, e.g. `.2px`.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would post the solution I'm using now. jus posted as answer to get the syntax coloring. The thing can be tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/385AY/2/

It's very lengthy, and some of the solutions here are much more compact.. but for anyone why may be able to use it, heres a version that is more accesible for beginners, and with comments..

```js
function css_value_validate(input) {

    // first get rid of any whitespace at beginning or end of sting
    input = $.trim(input);

    // now catch any keywords that should be allowed
    // this could be expanded for lots of keyword 
    // by holding allowed words in an object and 
    // checking against them
    if (input == 'auto') {
        return input;
    }

    // now get rid of anything that may precede the first occurence of a number or a dot 
    input = input.replace(/^[^0-9\.]*/, '');

    // add a leading zero if the input starts with a . and then a number
    input = input.replace(/(^\.[0-9]*)/, "0$1");

    var output = '';
    var numeric;

    // check of the input is a straight zero or an empty string and 
    if (input + '' === '0' || input + '' === '') {
        return input;
    }

    // get the raw numeric by parsing to float
    numeric = parseFloat(input);
    if (numeric != 'NaN') {
        if (numeric + '%' === input) {
            output = numeric + '%';
        } else if (numeric + 'em' === input) {
            output = numeric + 'em';
        } else {
            // if converted to pixels strip any decimals.
            // the 2nd parameter, 10, is the radix making sure we parse in decimal
            output = parseInt(numeric, 10);
            output = (output > 0) ? output + unit : output;
        }
    }

    return output;
} // END cssvalidate()
```

Comment: I'm not sure which answer to choose here, could you please vote for you favorites, and add some comments, then I'll choose the most popular.. (only I can choose an answer right?)

Answer (score -1):

If you use this regex to replace your data, you only need to tackle the ones with the missing prefix.

```
^((?<whole>\d+)(\.\d+){0,1}(?<valid>px|em|pt|%){0,1}.*|.*)$
```

First, replace this with

```
${whole}${valid}
```

If the regex isn't matched, the 2nd part (|.*) will be matched (anything) and the match will be replaced with nothing.

You could also go a line by line aproach & remove that part, when there is no match, swap it out in javascript with ''.

Lastly, just do a quick replace using

```
^(?<justdigits>\d+)$
```

and replace with

```
${justdigits}px
```

So, in short: Lots of ways to go about this, up to you how to continue.